# Why can't swift infer the closure type

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework, phimagemanager

First week into Swift, freshly created project with Swift 4.2 on Xcode 10.1), I'm [following a tutorial on a how to make a photo gallery app](https://youtu.be/HuVe_35AmpA?t=1629) I'm flabbergasted about a compiler error.

My situation is this, inside a custom **ViewController** inheriting from **UIViewController** and importing **UIKit** and **Photos**. This method is being called from **viewWillAppear** as **self.displayPhoto**.

**self.photosAsset** and **self.index** is being set by the previous viewController on the segue.

```
func displayPhoto() {
    let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
    var ID = imageManager.requestImage(
        for: self.photosAsset[self.index] as PHAsset,
        targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
        contentMode: .aspectFit,
        options: nil,
        resultHandler: { (result:UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!) in
            self.imgView.image = result
        }
    )
}
```

Xcode is complaining about **Unable to infer closure type in the current context** for the closure in the resultHandler. What type is there to infer?

[Looking at the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimage) it looks like the resultHandler has a void return type:

Comment: There is no type to infer as long as _you_ do not mess up the type inference by explicitly giving the wrong types.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but why the downvotes?

Comment: Well, you yourself linked to the documentation, where the answer was staring you in the face. The docs say `UIImage?`, you say `UIImage!` The docs say `[AnyHashable : Any]?`, you say `NSDictionary!` I didn’t downvote but I can see why someone would.

Answer (score 3):

In `resultHandler` you should use `(image, _)` instead of `(result:UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!)`

```
func displayPhoto() {
    let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
    var ID = imageManager.requestImage(
        for: self.photosAsset[self.index] as PHAsset,
        targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
        contentMode: .aspectFit,
        options: nil,
        resultHandler: { (image, _) in
            self.imgView.image = image
        }
    )
}
```

**Note:** To improve your method you may want to set `PHImageRequestOptions` in `options:`

```
func displayPhoto() {
    let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOption.isSynchronous = true
    requestOption.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    var ID = imageManager.requestImage(
        for: self.photosAsset[self.index] as PHAsset,
        targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
        contentMode: .aspectFit,
        options: requestOption,
        resultHandler: { (image, _) in
            self.imgView.image = image
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dictonary` instead of `NSDictionary`, but there is no need for declaring types of handler's parameters

```
... { result, info in
    ...
}
```

also you don't have to assign parameter of type `[AnyHashable : Any]?` because you don't need it, just put an underscore here `_`

```
... { image, _ in
    self.imgView.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are typing the closure incorrectly, yourself. The correct type is:

```
@escaping (UIImage?, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void
```

You have:

```
(result:UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!) in
```

which is wrong. That is very upsetting to the compiler! Just get out of the compiler's way and *let* it infer the types; it knows what they are better than you do. Write

```
result, info in
```

and all will be well.